# Truncate output of measurement to match significant digits of its error

Tags: awk, scripting, formatting

I want to automatically create a latex-table with measurements. The measurements are given in a text file in the following format:

```
#measurements #error
1.23456       0.00034
2.34567       0.34
```

and so on.

My problem is now that i want to have the data printed out in the following format:

```
#measurement(error)
1.23456(34)
2.34(34)
```

where the number of digits in brackets denotes the number of digits of the measurement subject to the uncertainty given in the brackets.

I get to the point of

```
#measurement(error)
1.23456(34)
2.34567(34000)
```

which is not very beautiful

by using

```
awk '{printf("%f(%d)\n", $1, $2*100000)}' datafile
```

Is there a way to truncate the output of the measurement according to the individual magnitude of the error.
I am not bound to awk, solutions employing other methods are very welcome too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
1$ awk 'NR==1; 
        NR>1 {n=match($2,/[1-9]/); 
              print substr($1,1,n+1) "(" substr($2,n) ")" }' file

#measurements #error
1.23456(34)
2.34(34)
```